# Time complexity for matching and counting between two lists

Tags: python, time-complexity

```
n_dicwords = [np.sum([c.lower().count(w.decode('utf-8')) for w in dictionary])
                                                for c in documents]
```

Here I am trying to determine my feature engineering computation time:

By using this line of code, which goes through every document and checks whether or not and if yes then how many its words also appear in this dictionary that I have, it generates a feature called *n_dicwords*. Sorry I am such a noob to complexity theory, I think the time complexity for generating this feature is O(n* m*w) where n is the number of documents, m is the number of words in each document and w is the number of words in the dictionary. Am I right? And if so is there any way to improve this?

Thank you so much! I am really appreciated for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm slightly surprised to note the the "x in s" construction in python is O(n), where n is the number of items n the list. So, your estimation is correct. A slightly more correct way of looking at it: Since your document or wor counts in said aren't changing at all, the important numbers are the total number of words which must be checked, and the length of the dictionary against which they are being checked. Obviously, this doesn't change the number of computations at all, it just gets us to a quickly recognizable form of O(m*n).

You could conceivably store your dictionary in a binary tree, which would reduce that to O(log(n)).

Search for "binary tree python" on Google, I was a few interesting things out there, like a package called "bintrees".

However, Erik Vesteraas points out the the python 'set' data structure is a hashed based collection, and has a complexity of O(1) in the average case, and O(n) in the worst, and highly rare case.

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set

Comment: Actually the standard set in python is a hash set(which for this use is even better) so no extra packages required.

Comment: Why are you surprised `x in s` is O(n)? It almost literally says "every `x` with index from 0 to `n-1` in `s`"..

Comment: No, "*for* x in s" says look at everything, "*if* x in s" doesn't have to look at everything.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the code underneath your code does any clever stuff your complexity analysis should be correct.

If performance in this part is important you should use a multiple-pattern string search algorithm, which attempts to solve pretty much the exact problem you are doing.

To start with have a look at [Aho-Corasick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) which is the most commonly used one and runs in linear time. Googling "Aho-Corasick python" turned up a few different implementations, so while I have not used any of them personally I would think you would not have to implement the algorithm itself to use it.

If you just need your code to run a little faster, and don't need to get the best performance you possibly could you could just use a set for the dictionary. In python a normal set is a hash set, so it has constant time lookup. Then you could just for each word check if it is in the dictionary.

Comment: I have changed my dictionary from type list to type set, but it seems it takes a bit more time now:start = time.clock()
`n_dicwords = [np.sum([c.lower().count(w.decode('utf-8')) for w in dictionary])
                                                for c in subsample_documents]
print "Time taken:", time.clock() - start

Time taken: 21.483408`

Comment: `dictionary_set = set(dictionary); n_dicwords = [np.sum([c.lower().count(w.decode('utf-8')) for w in dictionary_set]) for c in subsample_documents] print "Time taken:", time.clock() - start Time taken: 24.844395` Or is this normal that computation time can be inconsistent?

Comment: Iterating over a set is just as expensive as iterating over a list. You should iterate over the words in the document and for each word, check if it is in the dictionary. Now you are iterating over the words in the dictionary and for each of them checking if they are in the document, i.e. you are doing it the wrong way around.